# How can I debug intermittent failure of mkinitrd when updating kernel in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

I have a job to regularly create an AWS EC2 AMI based on the official AWS CentOS 7 image using [packer](https://www.packer.io/). Two of the last five builds have failed to produce a bootable image, because of this:

```
amazon-ebs: mkinitrd failed
amazon-ebs: warning: %posttrans(kernel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
amazon-ebs: Non-fatal POSTTRANS scriptlet failure in rpm package kernel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
```

The builds were all upgrading to the same version of the kernel, using `yum update -y`. The situation is now pretty open, but answering the following could be fruitful:

1. Is this a known problem? Does the kernel post-transaction script for example interact badly with another post-transaction script? I couldn't find anything related to this kernel version.
2. Can I increase the debug level of post-transaction scripts?
3. Can I expect to find a more detailed log of `mkinitrd` somewhere on the instance?

I could of course try reinstalling the kernel or re-running `mkinitrd`, but I'd rather understand the problem before I try hacking around it.

A possible early-detection issue would be how to tell `yum` to return a non-zero exit code if *any* part of package installation fails, but I couldn't find any options for this in `man yum`.